# Why don't we have any popular decentralized chat systems, social networks etc.?

Tags: java, websocket

Let's say two computers have the same decentralized chat program. Each user has to have an ip address and port number to send the message to another person. Each message is encrypted using, let's say, AES. The only problem is to know public keys. Is that it? If yes, why don't we have any popular decentralized chat system or social networks etc.? I am clearly missing something. Thank you.

**edit**: one more problem is that we can't know for sure probably, that message which is sent actually was sent by the user we think.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it will largely solicit opinion rather than facts.

Comment: @LucasKauffman I don't think that's true seeing tylerl's response.

Comment: Tyler's answer is good. The question is off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say I want to talk to some otherwise unknown person on the Internet. And I want the message to be encrypted. Establishing a secure link is easy; D-H key exchange makes sure eavesdropping is impossible. But whom did I just establish my connection to? Was it the person I thought, or perhaps some *other* otherwise unknown person on the Internet who's playing man-in-the-middle with us?

Encryption is useless without authentication because you could be establishing your encrypted connection to the bad guys, and the bad guys establishing a connection to me, which effectively means they can view or modify the connection as it goes by. Without authentication, it might as well be plain text. So how do we authenticate?

Well, you could generate an RSA key pair and send me your public key. Except how do I know that it was *you* sending me your public key and not the bad guys? If you gave it to me in person, then we'd have something. Otherwise we're back where we started. So how about you prove your identity to someone I trust whose public key I've already verified -- (maybe a trusted friend, maybe a company like Versign), they could sign your RSA key which could allow me to implicitly trust your public key by verifying the signatures on it.

That's pretty much the way SSL works and the way PGP works. You have to have some mechanism for trusting public keys, or the whole system is worthless. And that means that people have to *do something* to make sure that their public key is trusted. Meet in person, exchange keys over a trusted channel, or trust some third party.

But what all of these trust mechanisms have in common is that they're inconvenient. They're difficult for newbies to get right, and they're a load of effort that most people would rather avoid. **And this is why distributed encryted chat networks are never popular.**

Now that you know why it is inconvenient, go download [Off The Record](http://www.cypherpunks.ca/otr/) and add your decentralized encryption layer on top of your favorite chat protocol.

Comment: " Except how do I know that it was you sending me your public key and not the bad guys?" - Digital Signature?

Comment: @evening and I verify that digital signature using....? The public key you (or the bad guy) just sent me? If I already have a public key from you that I can trust for verifying your signature, then you don't need to sign *another* one to send me.

Comment: yes, got it. []

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, they are too complicated to use.  People like having a third party that they more or less trust to take care of the details for them.  With distributed systems, you have to put in too much effort yourself, so that rules it out for many people.  Then the people that don't mind don't have much in the way of motivation since there aren't enough people on it.

The systems do exist, but aren't popular due to these factors.

Comment: I've heard this complaint several times. I don't want to switch to another messenger/social network because all of my friends use it. It's time for an ad campaign by well known people to propose https://whistle.im/ or similar, gpg for E-Mail and a social network yet to be created to kill the existing ones.

Comment: @ott - not going to happen because those services are still too complex.  It requires running your own software, updates, security management, figuring out nodes to trust.  It's simply more effort than your general user wants to put in.